# Trying to join two tables in sqlalchemy orm query, getting an error

Tags: python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

Trying to join the tables below using this command:

```
Subscription.query.filter(    return Subscription.query.filter(Subscription.watch_id == id).join(User).filter_by(watch_id=id)
```

I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to <class 'app.user.model.User'>, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'wm_subscription' and 'user'.
```

Essentially my end goal is to get a query that gets a List of Users that share a watch_id. Not sure if the models or the query is correct. Anybody know what's wrong?

```
Database = declarative_base(cls=DbBase)
class Subscription(Database):
    __tablename__ = 'wm_subscription'
    subscription_id = UniqueIdPk()
    watch_id = UniqueIdRefNotNull(index=True)
    user_id = UniqueIdRefNotNull(ForeignKey('User.user_id'), index=True)

    subscription_watch = relationship('Watch',
                                      primaryjoin='Subscription.watch_id == Watch.watch_id',
                                      foreign_keys='Watch.watch_id',
                                      uselist=True)

    subscription_user = relationship('User',
                                     primaryjoin='Subscription.watch_id == User.user_id',
                                     foreign_keys='User.user_id',
                                     uselist=True,
                                     backref='user')

class User(Database, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = UniqueIdPk()

    # Google sub ID - unique to user https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect
    google_id = Column(String(length=50))

    # override email mixin for unique index
    email = Email(unique=True)

    first_name = Name()
    last_name = Name()

    def get_id(self):
        return self.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct query:

```
Subscription.query.filter(Subscription.watch_id == id).join(User)
```